# How are variables initialized in an angular factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, constructor, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I want to know if the constructor function of a angular factory can be used to run some code when the factory is initialized. For example , I have a factory service, where I want to print to console from that whenever the app starts or whenever this factory is called/initialized. Can somebody please explain ?

**Angular Factory:**

```
            app.factory('HomeFactory', function() {
            // create a object using constructor function
              var HomeFactory = function() {
                 console.log('in the constructor function');
              };
              HomeFactory.contactSubmit = function() {
                var self = this;
                console.log(self.model);
              }
              // returning the factory object
              return (HomeFactory);
              });
```

**Angular Controller:**

```
  app.controller('HomeController', function($scope, $state, HomeFactory) {
    $scope.HomeFactory = HomeFactory;
}
```

);

Comment: may be you need an instance of? `$scope.home = new HomeFactory()`?

Comment: also, your `contactSubmit` should be `HomeFactory.prototype.contactSubmit` with `this` instead of undefined `self`

Comment: Done, changed self to take 'this' reference. And I see lot of developers attaching the methods to prototype of the object, when both seems to work fine, I am sure there is a reason thats recommended.

Comment: For now difference is you define "static" method, your instances has not this function to call. to have `$scope.home.contactSubmit()` you should assign this function to prototype, or to this inside the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory you create is just a constructor function. you need to instantiate instances to call it:

```
$scope.home1 = new HomeFactory();
$scope.home2 = new HomeFactory();
```